# Generic webcam driver?

Tags: drivers, webcam

I'm trying to install an old Logitech webcam onto my laptop (which currently has a webcam) but can't find any drivers that work, even on the Logitech website.

**Webcam:** Logitech Quick-Cam Chat Webcam (QC Chat CA)
**OS:** Windows 7 x64 Home Premium

Where can I find a generic webcam driver that would work with any webcam?

Comment: What OS? What's the exact model of the webcam? These details will be useful in someone finding something that will work for you.

Comment: @Raystafarian that's all of the information i have, other than a serial code that might help, the serial code is QC Chat CA 961413-0215

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: windows 7 x64 home premium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Logitech, [this camera](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/435/281?WT.z_sp=Image) is the QuickCam Chat camera and [this camera](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/435/263?WT.z_sp=Image) is the Quick Camera Chat for Skype.  I'm not saying that one of these is the same as YOUR camera, but these are the ones that Logitech called "Chat" by name.

Now, wherever you got the Serial number from, there should also be a **MODEL** number, or M/N:.  Logitech was quite thorough about that.  I've got a *really* old Logitech Clicksmart 310 sitting here in front of me, and they were making sure to include the model number even back then.

Have you tried the Logitech Autodetection feature?  [Just choose Option 1](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support-downloads?selectedcrid=435) and allow the software to install, and detect the camera.  Make sure the camera is plugged into the computer.

EDIT:  I've found two different sites selling the same serial number, but what appears to be a different appearance.  [This one matches the first link at Logitech I gave you](http://www.youfindit.ca/logitech/webcams/10431312) and [This one](http://www.buymebuyme.com/buy/Logitech-961413-0215-QuickCam-Chat-USB-Web-Cam-with-FREE-Headset-WHITE-BLUE.html) which doesn't match either image at Logitech, but most likely has the same internal hardware.  This leads me to believe that the first link I gave you is the right one.... so the drivers for M/N:V-UAP42 should do the trick.

Comment: it worked! THANK YOU! and yeah the first one you gave my was correct

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Linux, the gspca driver for v4l [supports the Logitech QC Chat](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/video4linux/gspca.txt;h=e6c2842407a488f4af6d26d911a3bc80538d5d64;hb=HEAD)(line 79), and has since it's [initial release 2008-07-20](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/video4linux/gspca.txt;hb=63eb9546dcb5e9dc39ab88a603dede8fdd18e717), included in Linux 2.6.27.

To use it,

```
sudo modprobe gspca_zc3xx
```

Though, this is likely handled by udev when it's detected.

The option in the kernel configuration is `CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_ZC3XX`.

Comment: i will keep that in mind next time i use linux, thanks!